# How to display text of Check Box on multiple lines automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, richtextbox

I made a quiz that stores the questions in a `SQL database` and display the question in a `Rich Text Box` and the answers in `Check Boxes`.

But sometimes the *answer is too long and I need more space to show it*. I thought that a `multiline` would help me, but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to combine the two answers below ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms checkboxes have an `AutoSize` property that is set to `true` by default.*
If you set it to `false`, you can change the height of the checkbox and it's text would wrap automatically.
However, if the `AutoSize` property is set to `false`, you must to set the width and height of checkbox yourself.

*As TaW mentioned in his comment, the `AutoSize` property's default is `true` only when adding the checkbox in the designer. For dynamically created checkboxes the default is `false`.

Comment: The default is only true for Checkboxes added in the designer. Dynamically generated checkboxes have it false by default. Go figure..

Comment: @Taw thanks, I didn't know that. Will include that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of the checkbox you will automatically get multiline.
I made a simple example of how to set the width of the control (if you want the width set hard) and then just adapting the height.
Its better to set the height correct or the text might be clipped.

Try this:

```
    private void CreateCheckBox(){
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        cb.Width = 150;
        Controls.Add(cb);
        cb.Text = "This is a long text that needs to be broken down into multiple lines.";
        cb.Height = GetHeight(cb);
    }

    private static int GetHeight(CheckBox cb) {
        using (Graphics g = cb.CreateGraphics()) {
            var size = g.MeasureString(cb.Text, cb.Font);
            int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double) size.Width/cb.Width));
            return (int)(rows*size.Height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works with dynamically generated checkboxes as their AutoSize propeerty is false by default. Those added in the designer need to have theirs unset explicitly.